# Deploy service to customer's local network and how to guarantee code security

Tags: python, security, encryption, keras, virtual-machine

We have to deploy our service to customer's local network (offline), and guarantee our code's security.

Our project's framework is python + keras, we conceive of the following ways:

1. Depoly all the code to a local VM or Docker, but how can we avoid being cracked or hacked?
2. Obfuscate python code and encrypt keras deep learning model (contains network structure, lots of params), but how can we encrypt our keras model?

Thanks.

Comment: Your service runs on their machines -> your code is accessible by them.

Comment: it's accessible by them, but less understand the code's internal logic .